# Laravel Validator throws Connection Reset

Tags: php, laravel, validation

### This is my Controller Code (Error Line):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), EmployeeCapitalBenefit::getCreateValidationRules());
```

### This is my `$request`:

[image]

### This is my EmployeeCaptialBenefit Model:

```
use App\Traits\HasValidationRules;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployeeCapitalBenefit extends Model
{

    use HasValidationRules;

    // Statische Variablen
    public static array $createValidationRules = [
        'valid_from' => 'required|date',
        'valid_until' => 'required|date',
        'institute' => 'required|string',
        'iban' => 'required',
        'sum_employer' => 'required|double',
        'sum_employee' => 'required|double',
    ];

    public static array $updateValidationRules = [
        'valid_from' => 'date',
        'valid_until' => 'date',
        'institute' => 'string',
        'sum_employer' => 'double',
        'sum_employee' => 'double',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'valid_from',
        'valid_until',
        'institute',
        'sum_employer',
        'sum_employee',
    ];
---------------------------------
```

### This is my Error Message:

### [image]

I have no Idea whats wrong, everything seems right.

In the Debugg Mode, the Controller Line (Validator::make) loads like 3 seconds until error Message and sometimes the debugger just goes to top of Method and rerun and then the error Message throws

Comment: the error is in the Javascript and related to your network. not the right place to post it here. try https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic and take a look at this common issue https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/ (proxy in place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

```
class EmployeeCapitalBenefit extends Model
{
```

### to:

```
class EmployeeCapitalBenefit extends BaseModel
{
```